# How to add tooltips to chart.js graph

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working on a webapp and I recently swapped google charts with chart.js because it is visually more appealing. However, the one loss that I took is that I can no longer get tooltips above the data points. I was wondering if anyone knows how this can be done as I am a novice with javascript. Here is the code for the graph and the settings:

```
    var data = {
            labels : graphData[0],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(200,160,100,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(80,240,70,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(80,240,70,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : graphData[3]
                },
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : graphData[1]
                },
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : graphData[2]
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            scaleShowGridLines : true,
            scaleShowLabels : true,
            animationSteps : 150,
            scaleOverride: true,
            scaleSteps : Math.max.apply(Math, graphData[3]),
            scaleStepWidth : 1,
            scaleStartValue : 1
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_div").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width  = Math.max(graphData[0].length * 60, 600);
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data,options);
        $('#chart_area').fadeIn();
        $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#picture_area").offset().top
         }, 1000);
```

Comment: have you figure it out how to implement tooltips?

Comment: get the newest Chart.js library it should have builtin tooltip, then to activate it add it in option `{showTooltips:true}` and refer the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) to modify it

Answer (score 1):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        showTooltips: true,
        multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
    });
```

use this to set a gloabl settings in chartjs.